# Передача JSESSIONID в новом запросе для коректной идентификации на сервере

Tags: android, okhttp

Всем привет.
   Помогите пожалуйста с такой такой ситуацией.
   Нужно отправлять запросы к серверу обычным HTTP. При этом на сервере используется механизм сессий для последующих идентификаций запросов (JSESSIONID  || PHPSESSID - неважно.)
   В качестве клиента пробывал использовать OkHTTPClient и Retrofit 2. Но все мои попытки прокинуть туда это параметр венчаетса неудачей ибо сервер потом назад отправляет новый JSESSIONID.
   Пример моих действий
   интерфейс

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("client/signIn")
Call<responseT2> loginPost(@Field("email") String email, @Field("pass") String pass, @Header("Set-Cookie") String string);   
//-----------------------------------------------
в синглтоне  создаю:
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor())
            .build();
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(http://api.example.net/)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
```

Код за которым делаю запрос

```
beck = retrofit.create(BackEndApi.class);
```

//------------

```
Call<responseT2> call = beck.loginPost(
                    r.getEmail(),
                    r.getPass(),
                    NewNetUtil.getJSESSIOINID()
            );
            call.enqueue(new Callback<responseT2>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<responseT2> call, Response<responseT2> response) {
                                            NewNetUtil.setJSESSIOINID(response.headers().get("Set-Cookie"));
                                        }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<responseT2> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.v("response", "ERORR");
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            .build();
```

Что мне нужно изменить или добавить, чтобы сервер каждый мой запрос принимал в рамках одной сессии.
Буду благодарен ...

Comment: Если он высылает новый jsessionid, значит Вы ему вернули какой-то не правильный. Что это у Вас за NewNetUtil.getJSESSIOINID/setJSESSIOINID?

Comment: @Sergey - синглтон - где гранитса JSESSIONID, чтоб можна было "подкидывать" его в запросы

Comment: @Sergey -  Проверял, если  не добавлять - то Stetho (Developer tool) - не показивает что такой кук отправляетса

Comment: Может куки как-то неправильно хранится? Ошибок в getJSESSIOINID/setJSESSIOINID нет?

Comment: @Sergey -  getJSESSIOINID/setJSESSIOINID - там просто get/set без модификаций

Answer (score 0):

Задача решена, оказалось проблема з названиях кук.

```
Call<responseT2> loginPost(@Field("email") String email, @Field("pass") String pass, @Header("Set-Cookie") String string);
```

1. вместо Set-Cookie нада : Cookie или cookie
2. сервер отправляет Set-Cookie только один раз - при входе в систему, и отправляет идентификатор внутри этого кука.

Моя ошибка оказалась на поверхности, при каждом запросе я считывал с хедеров

```
NewNetUtil.setJSESSIOINID(response.headers().get("Set-Cookie"));
```

Нужно только первый раз его считать, сохранить в системе, и потом при каждом запросе его подкидывать в хедер (Cookie или cookie) или в конструкторе через @Header или через Interceptor запросов в OkHttpClient.Builder()